# How to handle Google Analytics for Android and Website

Tags: android, google-analytics, web

I have a news website with X amount of monthly visitors, which I keep track of using Google Analytics. Now, I'm about to publish an Android App and it allows you to browse the same news with the advantages of a native app for your mobile device, but I don't know how to handle Analytics for this app.

I mean, its good that I can track user interaction on my Android app, but I'm afraid that my website's Analytics will suffer big visits drop if the app ends up being popular.

On my website, you can basically browse categories (list of articles) and read those articles, and I keep track of every link you click, and at the end of the day I use this information to sell ad slots. I plan to track these same events on my Android app, but if my website's Analytics reports a huge visits drop, then I'm afraid my ad slots won't sell much.

Is there a way to link website analytics with app analytics so that my numbers keep steady?

If not, then, how should I handle analytics for my app? Should I create a new independent Account for my app or should I create a new property just for mobile app under my website Account?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Now you can combine different devices in the same report. As pointed out [here](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2340760/Google-Analytics-Combines-Data-From-All-Devices-Renames-Visits-Visitors): "If you use the same property ID for a website and your mobile app, both sets of data will now appear in the same reports". More info in the [official announcement](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleAnalytics/posts/LCLgkyCn4Zi).

Then you could segment the data (app vs website) in several different ways (depending on what type of analysis you want to make, if its recurring or one-time, etc.):

> - Use a filter
> - Create custom dashboards
> - Use advanced segments
> - Use secondary dimensions
> - Create custom reports

Another question would be if strategically/commercially it is more interesting to show the stats and sell the ads together or differenciate between app and website, but this is outside of the scope of Stackoverflow (not a programming/technical question).